# Reuse Spring Data Couchbase configuration in my application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm using couchbase with Spring data and its repositories and it's working very good. The problem is now that I have to query some old documents that aren't managed by Spring.

I understand that I should  create a single `CouchbaseEnvironment` and reuse it acoording to the docs. https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/developer/java-2.1/env-config.html

So what I tried to do is to @Autowire the couchbase environment bean created by Spring and it worked fine I could open and query the bucket I needed. But once the application is shut down, there are some errors that says that the pool manager is rejecting extra tasks:

```
    Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@43d89a1d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@2118de9d[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at rx.Observable$27.onError(Observable.java:7997) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:159) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.onError(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:227) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onError(AsyncSubject.java:115) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.decode(AbstractGenericHandler.java:245) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$2.decode(MessageToMessageCodec.java:81) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted 
    Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@43d89a1d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@2118de9d[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@43d89a1d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@2118de9d[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:632) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker.scheduleActual(NewThreadWorker.java:239) ~[rxjava-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.env.CoreScheduler.scheduleDirect(CoreScheduler.java:151) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.scheduleDirect(AbstractGenericHandler.java:369) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.publishResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:332) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.decode(AbstractGenericHandler.java:237) ~[core-io-1.2.9.jar:na]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

This error keeps appearing even after the application is restarted. And this error doesn't happen when I don't reuse the couchbase environment.

My question is, if I need to open a bucket, should I create a Cluster in this new configuration or should I reuse this one too?

Thanks.